# Pandas: Read skipping lines that starts with a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
[6 rows x 5 columns]
name     timestamp         value1  state         value2
Cs01  1.514483e+09         19.516      0  9.999954e-01   
Cs02  1.514483e+09         20.055      0  9.999363e-01   
Cs03  1.514483e+09         20.054      0  9.999970e-01   
Cs01  1.514483e+09         20.055      0  9.999949e-01   
Cs01  1.514483e+09         10.907      0  9.963121e-01   
Cs02  1.514483e+09         10.092      0  1.548312e-02
```

is it possible with the read_csv function skip all the rows that does not start with the name "Cs01"?

Thank you

Comment: It would be useful if you could include the desired output as your question is slightly confusing on first read

Comment: exactly what you have done. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The simpliest is filter all rows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file')

df = df[df['name'].str.startswith('Cs01')]
print (df)
   name     timestamp  value1  state    value2
0  Cs01  1.514483e+09  19.516      0  0.999995
3  Cs01  1.514483e+09  20.055      0  0.999995
4  Cs01  1.514483e+09  10.907      0  0.996312
```

Another solution is get all rows not contains `Cs01` in preprocessing and use parameter `skiprows` in `read_csv`:

```
exclude = [i for i, line in enumerate(open('file.csv')) if not line.startswith('Cs01')]
print (exclude)
[0, 2, 3, 6]

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows = exclude[1:])
print (df)
   name     timestamp  value1  state    value2
0  Cs01  1.514483e+09  19.516      0  0.999995
1  Cs01  1.514483e+09  20.055      0  0.999995
2  Cs01  1.514483e+09  10.907      0  0.996312
```

Answer (score 4):

One method would be to read the file in chunks and then filter the lines out in the chunks, it's possible this will be faster if you have a large file with a lot of unwanted rows as reading in the entire df and then filtering may be non-performant:

```
In[17]:
t="""name     timestamp         value1  state         value2
Cs01  1.514483e+09         19.516      0  9.999954e-01   
Cs02  1.514483e+09         20.055      0  9.999363e-01   
Cs03  1.514483e+09         20.054      0  9.999970e-01   
Cs01  1.514483e+09         20.055      0  9.999949e-01   
Cs01  1.514483e+09         10.907      0  9.963121e-01   
Cs02  1.514483e+09         10.092      0  1.548312e-02"""
d = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True, chunksize=2)
dfs = pd.concat([x[x['name'].str.startswith('Cs01')] for x in d])
dfs

Out[17]: 
   name     timestamp  value1  state    value2
0  Cs01  1.514483e+09  19.516      0  0.999995
3  Cs01  1.514483e+09  20.055      0  0.999995
4  Cs01  1.514483e+09  10.907      0  0.996312
```

Here the `chunksize` param specifies the number of lines to read, you can set this to some arbritrary size, you then do a list comprehension and filter on each chunk and then call [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to produce a single df

Comment: Down-voting as it's unclear what you mean by this answer.

Comment: @Andre what do you not understand? `Chunksize` will read a specific number of rows on each iteration, so it returns a df, each df chunk is filtered and appended to a list and then concatenated. Most `pandas` users understand this